# show that if the sequence {Sn} is bounded, then {Sn/n} must be convergent.

Tags: real-analysis

If {Sn} is bounded prove that {Sn/n} is convergent

Here is what i have so far:
Since Sn is bounded it has a M Least upper bound such that abs(Sn)<=M. Then by multiplying both sides by 1/n we get abs(Sn/n)<=M(1/n)

Comment: Note that $\{S_n/n\}$ is *not* a subsequence of $\{S_n\}$.

Comment: Also, boundedness of a set does not imply that the set has a maximum and a minimum.

Comment: Really, the worst part is the introduction of $1.9$, etc. A [non sequitur](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non_sequitur_%28literary_device%29).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your argument so far doesn't quite make sense.

A better way to approach it would be to let $M$ be any bound on $\{S_n\}$, and $\epsilon > 0$. Then if $N$ is large enough and $n \ge N$, we have

$$\left|\frac{S_n}{n}\right| \le M \frac{1}{n} < \epsilon$$

Do you see what the limit is, and how to select $N$ given $\epsilon$?

Comment: I see how you started with Sn <= M and multiplied both sides by 1/n. But where to go i am clueless.

Comment: @james Note that $|S_n/n|$ can be made as small as we like by careful choice of $N$. So the limit must be zero.

Comment: Oh! I was not thinking it was that simple. i haven't done proofs in 5 years. I am very rusty. I kept thinking there is more to it than that.